# Minecraft Bedrock Dedicated Server Libssl Library Error

Tags: server, minecraft

When I try to start the Minecraft bedrock server using ./bedrock_server or LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server it has this error >

./bedrock_server: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried installing libssl again, reflashing ubuntu instance, tried running export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64 >
sudo ldconfig, and tried running ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1, ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1.... But nothing seems to work and I couldn't find any other artilces or help request on forums so here I am.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is on Ubuntu 22.04, which has libssl3 by default, you need to install the libssl1.1 package. You can get it from https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libssl1.1

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

After that, it should be possible to start the server as per official instructions

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022-07-14, Impish is EOLed so you'll want to get it from the Focal repo. How I did it:

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install libssl1.1
```

It's usually a good idea to go through a package manager rather than download and dpkg yourself (because of the complications of uninstalling, updating, etc). But if that's the route you want to go down, you could find the Focal version of the package, download and dpkg if you wanted.